# Apex Map using "Name" as key

Tags: apex, map

I'm trying create a **Map** using a **name field as key**.

Sample code:

```
Set<String> priceBooksNames = new Set<String>();
priceBooksNames.add('LN-200');
priceBooksNames.add('LN-100');

Map<string,PriceBook2> priceBooks = new Map<string,PriceBook2>([SELECT name,id FROM PriceBook2 WHERE name=:priceBooksNames ]);
system.debug(priceBooks.get('LN-100')); //this is returning NULL
```

I can see on console that setId on map is not getting the name field value.

```
VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT [5]|priceBooks|{"serId":1,"value":{"01sb0000000hiqQAAQ":{"serId":2,"value":{"Name":"LN-100 ADULTOS","Id":"01sb0000000hiqQAAQ"}},"01sb0000000hiqGAAQ":{"serId":3,"value":{"Name":"LN-200 EMPRESAS","Id":"01sb0000000hiqGAAQ"}}}}
```

What I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As far as I'm aware the map constructor only supports ID-->Sobject.

If you want a different key, then you have to build the map yourself.

```
Map<String, PriceBook2> priceBooks = new Map<String, PriceBook2>();
for (Pricebook2 p : [SELECT name,id FROM PriceBook2 WHERE name=:priceBooksNames ]) {
   priceBooks.put(p.name, p);
}
```

Comment: Agree, here is the doc: [Maps from SObject Arrays](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#CSHID=langCon_apex_collections_maps_from_SObjects.htm|StartTopic=Content%2FlangCon_apex_collections_maps_from_SObjects.htm|SkinName=webhelp)

Comment: For a more general sObject the `name` may not be unique and you would need to add extra checks to see if it is already in the Map keys.

Answer (score -1):

```
List<string> strList = new list<string>();
strList.add('LN-200');
strList.add('LN-100');

system.debug(strList);

// for Testing purpose
PriceBook2 pbk = new PriceBook2();

pbk.name='LN-200';
insert pbk;

map<string, PriceBook2 > pbkMap= new map<string, PriceBook2 >();
list<PriceBook2 > pbkList = [select id, name from PriceBook2 ];
for (PriceBook2 pbk: pbkList )
{
    pbkMap.put(pbk.name, pbk);
}
system.debug(pbkMap.get('LN-200')); //returns the correct pricebook data
```

Comment: Yes, but the existing answer from 9 years ago is more to the point and provides an explanation. The explanation is as important as the solution itself.