# getting System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Tags: apex, class

in Execute Anonymous, executing the following code to test the class:

```
List<Contact> contacts = [Select c.Territory__c, c.Sub_county_Code__c, c.Student_Type__c, c.Domestic_Or_International__c, c.Recruiter_Code__c, c.Name, c.MailingState, c.Home_Schooled__c, c.High_School__c, c.Current_County_Code__c From Contact c where c.Name = 'Glenn Bargo'];
system.debug('******************************Before execution of assigning territory values: ');
ContactTerritoryUpdateClass.setTerritoryValues(contacts);
system.debug('******************************After execution of assigning territory values: ');
```

The class looks like this:

```
public class ContactTerritoryUpdateClass {
/***************
 * When an Admissions Contact is created or updated, need to evaluate the 
 * information provided to determine the appropriate territory assigned.
****************/
    public static void setTerritoryValues(Contact[] contacts){

        Id terrOut;
        Id terrIn;
        String mailState;
        String mailCounty;
        String mailSubCounty;
        String terrName;
        Set<ID> schoolIds = new Set<Id>();
        for (Contact co:contacts){
            if (co.High_School__c != NULL) {
                schoolIds.add(co.High_School__c);
            }
        }

        // Currently, there are less than 300 territories and not much chance of growing
        Map<string, Territory__c> allTerr = new Map<string, Territory__C>(
        [select Name from Territory__c]);

        Map<ID, Account> allSchools = new Map<ID, Account>(
        [select Territory__c from Account
         where Type = 'High School'
         and   Id in :schoolIds]);

        for (Contact c:contacts){
            terrIn = c.Territory__c;
            mailState = c.MailingState;
            mailCounty = c.Current_County_Code__c;
            mailSubCounty = c.Sub_county_Code__c;

            if (c.Domestic_Or_International__c == 'International') {
                terrOut = allTerr.get(c.Domestic_Or_International__c).Id; 

            } else if (c.Student_Type__c == 'Transfer') {
                terrOut = allTerr.get(c.Student_Type__c).Id;

            } else if (c.Student_Type__c == 'Freshman') {
                if (c.High_School__c != NULL){
                    terrOut = allSchools.get(c.High_School__c).Territory__c;

                } else if (c.Home_Schooled__c) {
                    if (c.MailingState == 'WI') {
                        terrName = mailState + '-' + mailCounty;
                        system.debug('WI home school terrName coming back with - ' + terrName);
                        terrOut = allTerr.get(terrName).Id;

                    } else if (c.MailingState == 'IL') {
                        if (mailCounty == 'Cook') {
                            terrName = mailState + '-Cook2';
                            system.debug('IL home school terrName coming back with - ' + terrName);
                            terrOut = allTerr.get(terrName).Id;

                        } else if (mailCounty == 'De Kalb') {
                            terrName = mailState + '-De Kalb2';
                            system.debug('IL home school terrName coming back with - ' + terrName);
                            terrOut = allTerr.get(terrName).Id;

                        } else if (mailCounty == 'du Page') {
                            terrName = mailState + '-du Page1';
                            system.debug('IL home school terrName coming back with - ' + terrName);
                            terrOut = allTerr.get(terrName).Id;

                        } else if (mailCounty == 'Kane') {
                            terrName = mailState + '-Kane1';
                            system.debug('IL home school terrName coming back with - ' + terrName);
                            terrOut = allTerr.get(terrName).Id;

                        } else {
                            terrName = mailState + '-' + mailCounty;
                            system.debug('IL home school terrName coming back with - ' + terrName);
                            terrOut = allTerr.get(terrName).Id;

                        }
                    } else {
                        //terrName = mailState;
                        system.debug('Other home school terrName coming back with - ' + mailState);
                        terrOut = allTerr.get(mailState).Id;
                    }
                }

            }
            if (terrIn <> terrOut) {
                    c.Territory__c = terrOut;
                }
            }
        }

}
```

The log looks like this:

```
DEBUG LOG

28.0 APEX_CODE,FINE;APEX_PROFILING,INFO;CALLOUT,INFO;DB,INFO;VALIDATION,INFO;WORKFLOW,INFO
Execute Anonymous: List<Contact> contacts = [Select c.Territory__c,
c.Sub_county_Code__c, c.Student_Type__c,
c.Domestic_Or_International__c, c.Recruiter_Code__c, c.Name,
c.MailingState, c.Home_Schooled__c, c.High_School__c,
c.Current_County_Code__c From Contact c where c.Name = 'Glenn Bargo'];
Execute Anonymous: system.debug('******************************Before
execution of assigning territory values: '); Execute Anonymous:
ContactTerritoryUpdateClass.setTerritoryValues(contacts); Execute
Anonymous: system.debug('******************************After execution
of assigning territory values: '); 13:03:39.059
(59199000)|EXECUTION_STARTED 13:03:39.059
(59211000)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|execute_anonymous_apex
13:03:39.060 (60283000)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[1]|Aggregations:0|select
c.Territory__c, c.Sub_county_Code__c, c.Student_Type__c,
c.Domestic_Or_International__c, c.Recruiter_Code__c, c.Name,
c.MailingState, c.Home_Schooled__c, c.High_School__c,
c.Current_County_Code__c from Contact c where c.Name = 'Glenn Bargo'
13:03:39.086 (86191000)|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[1]|Rows:1 13:03:39.086
(86390000)|USER_DEBUG|[2]|DEBUG|******************************Before
execution of assigning territory values:  13:03:39.096
(96456000)|METHOD_ENTRY|[1]|01pG00000034mOr|ContactTerritoryUpdateClass.ContactTerritoryUpdateClass()
13:03:39.096 (96482000)|METHOD_EXIT|[1]|ContactTerritoryUpdateClass
13:03:39.096
(96543000)|METHOD_ENTRY|[3]|01pG00000034mOr|ContactTerritoryUpdateClass.setTerritoryValues(LIST<Contact>)
13:03:39.096 (96662000)|SYSTEM_CONSTRUCTOR_ENTRY|[14]|<init>(Integer)
13:03:39.096 (96730000)|SYSTEM_CONSTRUCTOR_EXIT|[14]|<init>(Integer)
13:03:39.097 (97507000)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[22]|Aggregations:0|select
Name from Territory__c 13:03:39.103
(103670000)|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[22]|Rows:238 13:03:39.106
(106133000)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[25]|Aggregations:0|select Territory__c
from Account where (Type = 'High School' and Id = :tmpVar1)
13:03:39.112 (112164000)|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[25]|Rows:0 13:03:39.112
(112716000)|USER_DEBUG|[81]|DEBUG|Other home school terrName coming
back with - TN 13:03:39.112
(112891000)|EXCEPTION_THROWN|[82]|System.NullPointerException: Attempt
to de-reference a null object 13:03:39.113
(113020000)|METHOD_EXIT|[3]|01pG00000034mOr|ContactTerritoryUpdateClass.setTerritoryValues(LIST<Contact>)
13:03:39.113 (113165000)|FATAL_ERROR|System.NullPointerException:
Attempt to de-reference a null object

Class.ContactTerritoryUpdateClass.setTerritoryValues: line 82, column
1 AnonymousBlock: line 3, column 1 AnonymousBlock: line 3, column 1
```

Territory is custom object and the value TN is in that object.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that when you are doing this

```
terrOut = allTerr.get(mailState).Id;
```

The allTerr.get(mailState) is not bringing back a record.

But, you say, why isn't allTerr.get('TN') working since you have a TN record?

Well, because when you initialise the map allTerr you have thought that the key is the name but it is not it is the Salesforce ID of the Territory__c record. See this answer

[Apex Map using "Name" as key](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/16452/apex-map-using-name-as-key/16453#16453)

So instead of doing this

```
Map<string, Territory__c> allTerr = new Map<string, Territory__C>([select Name from Territory__c]);
```

You should do this:

```
Map<String, Territory__c> allTerr = new Map<String, Territory__c>();
for (Territory__c t : [select Name from Territory__c]) {
   allTerr.put(t.name, t);
}
```

And the map will have the key that you expect, and you will not bring back null when you search for 'TN' in it.

--Edit--

You could also consider some defensive coding

```
if (allTerr.get(mailState) != null) {
   //then it is safe to refer to properties so go ahead
   terrOut = allTerr.get(mailState).Id;
} else {
   //you didn't expect this, there wasn't an entry to match the state but maybe
   //corrupt data got into the system somehow and you can now handle it elegantly
}
```