# How can I create Map<String code, String ID> from a SOQL query

Tags: apex, map

I want to get a map of rate_code and ID instead of Id and Rate object directly from SOQL query.

If i run following query then i will have to iterate over rateMap map to create `Map<String rate_code , String ID>`. Is there any other efficient way to get this kind of result directly using soql OR by doing minimal manipulations in apex code ?

```
Map<String, Rate> rateMap = [select id, rate_code from Rate];
```

Comment: I fear that you have to do it by iterating over the result. There is no "direct" method to do the same

Comment: Check out [this question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/16452/apex-map-using-name-as-key) for the code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code below would be the simplest way to do it using a [for each loop](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_loops_for_SOQL.htm). It will stop you hitting a heap size limit if you are iterating over a lot of records, which you could potentially be doing as there is no where condition on your SOQL.

```
Map<String, Id> rateMap = new Map<String, Id>();    
for (Rate r : [select Id, rate_code from Rate]) {
    rateMap.put(r.rate_code, r.Id);
}
```

Also keep in mind that your rate_code may not be unique and potentially cause Rates to be excluded from the map. `Map<String, List<Id>>` may be a better way.